# Unpacking integrals in QFT and their notation

Tags: momentum, field-theory, vectors, notation, integration

In a standard QFT course integrals are often written $$\int d^4pf(p)=\int dp^0\int dp^1\int dp^2 \int dp^3f(p^0,p^1,p^2,p^3).$$ This is just the standard notation for packing in a lot of math into a short expression. I understand the notation when put like this but applying this notation I have been having some trouble with. Take the integral $$\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{p^2+m^2}.$$ To solve this we recall that our 4-momentum $p$ is $p=(p^0,p^1,p^2,p^3)$. Therefore, in the (+,-,-,-) metric signature we have that $$p^2=(p^0)^2-(p^1)^2-(p^2)^2-(p^3)^2.$$ Now we can just insert that into the integral and get the result using standard techniques. However, I saw on another post on here that this can be written $$\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{p^2+m^2}=\int \frac{dp^0}{(2\pi)}\frac{1}{(p^0)^2+m^2}\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{p^2+m^2}.$$ The integration was over a contour. When I saw this post I thought that we could repeat the steps for $p^1,p^2,p^3$and just get the 4 integrals with the square of each of the individual components of the 4-momentum in the denominator. Is that the right approach? Furthermore if we just have $$\int d^4p\frac{1}{p}$$ is it true that this would imply $$\int d^4p\frac{1}{p}=\int dp^0\frac{1}{p^0}\int dp^1\frac{1}{p^1}...?$$ In general my question is: How do we unpack integrals of the form listed in the first like of equation to actually evaluate them? I have done extensive research on this and haven't found a solid answer yet.

Comment: You seem to be missing some minus signs in the $p^2 = \dots$ equation. Also, could you link to the other post you are referring to?

Comment: @Noiralef I tried looking for the post put couldn't find the link to it. The Included equations is how the integral was unpacked. I'm wondering if we can do that process anytime or if not, what the general strategy is to unpack integrals using the shorthand notation for d dimensional space.

Comment: It sounds like the other post was either wrong, or you misunderstood it... if you can't even find it, it might be better to just forget about it. Integrals in QFT aren't magic. Try renaming the variables to $x$, $y$ and $z$ and see if the results would make sense in an introductory calculus course.

Comment: @knzhou The variables arnt the problem. I just am not understanding how to unpack integrals using the $\int d^4p f(p)$, for some 4-vector p. Take $\int d^4pp$. I'm just not understanding how to actually evaluate something in that form. The names of the variables is fine and multi dimensional integration is fine the notation is the only thing confusing me.

Comment: $\int d^4p \, p$ doesn't make sense because $p$ is a four-vector. If you mean $\int d^4p \, p^\mu$, that's actually four different four-fold integrals, depending on the value of $\mu$. For example, for $\mu = 0$ it's $\int dp^0 \int dp^1 \int dp^2 \int dp^3 \, p^0$. Nothing here is different from calculus class.

Comment: That's what I thought, just was extremely confused for some reason. Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes (perhaps confusingly), $p$ is written as a short-hand for $\sqrt{ p^\mu p_\mu }$